# asking the container to notify your application whenever a session is about to timeout in Java

Tags: java, session, timeout, containers

Which method(s) can be used to ask the container to notify your application whenever a session is about to timeout?(choose all that apply)

A. HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed              -- correct

B. HttpSessionBindingListener.valueBound

C. HttpSessionBindingListener.valueUnbound       -- correct this is kind of round-about but if you have an attribute class this is a way to be informed of a timeout

D. HttpSessionBindingEvent.sessionDestroyed      -- no such method

E. HttpSessionAttributeListener.attributeRemoved  -- removing an attribute isn’t tightly associated with a session timeout

F. HttpSessionActivationListener.sessionWillPassivate  -- session passivation is different than timeout

I agree with option A.

1) But C is doubtful

How can value unbound be tightly coupled with session timeout.It is just the callback method when an attribute gets removed.

2) and if C is correct, E should also be correct.

HttpSessionAttributeListener is just a class that wants to know when any type of attribute has been added, removed, or replaced in a session. It is implemented by any class.

HttpSessionBindingListener exists so that the attribute itself can find out when it has been added to or removed from a session and the attribute class must implement this interface to achieve it.

Any ideas…

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to use A. Remember that `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()` is called before the session is invalidated so all its attributes are intact.

Our application uses a session attribute with key `"LOGOUT"` to signify an explicit logout. So your code may look something like this:

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    Object logout = se.getSession().getAttribute("LOGOUT");
    String username = (String)se.getSession().getAttribute("USERNAME");
    auditLog.info("User '" + username + "' " +
                 (logout == null ? "timed" : "logged") +
                 " out.");
}
```

As far as I can tell there is no standard way to tell from the `HttpSession` why it is about to be invalidated and, amazingly, there is no information in the `HttpSessionEvent` object that describes what the event was (this is true up to [Java EE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html)).